# Enabling SSH by default on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian, ssh, services, raspbian-stretch

I have a Raspberry Pi 1 Model A running an image of [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

I've noticed that when I power on my pi and allow it to start up, I can't seem to SSH into it from my Mac laptop. *First*, I have to hook my RPi up to a keyboard and monitor, log into it (with the default `pi` user, which is fine for now), and then effectively "bounce" SSH manually:

```
sudo service ssh stop
sudo service ssh start
```

Once I do this, I can then SSH into the RPi (from my Mac) without any problems.

I *believe* this means SSH is not running by default at startup. How can I confirm this is the case, and how can I fix it so that I can have the following dev/test cycle:

1. Power on the pi
2. Give it a minute or two to boot up
3. SSH into it from my Mac

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH not working with fresh install](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to do this for a headless setup is to create a file named `ssh` on the boot partition of the SD card. This will enable the SSH daemon immediately after first boot and will be deleted.

Official SSH guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md#3-enable-ssh-on-a-headless-raspberry-pi-add-file-to-sd-card-on-another-machine

This and more for the headless setup can also be found on the Raspberry Pi forum:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191252

Comment: I just confirmed that this procedure works as expected on the RPi A using a fresh raspbian stretch install.

Comment: Does NOT work on November raspbian stretch

Comment: The documentation says this in this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md

Comment: I just confirmed this procedure on my Linux PC where I had the microsd card mounted under /media/fred.  I issued the commands: `cd /media/fred/boot` then `touch ssh`  Then I unmounted the microsd card, removed it from my PC and then inserted it into my Raspberry Pi and booted the Pi.  I could then ssh to the Pi from my Linux PC. e.g.  `ssh pi@192.168.0.2`.  This is on raspbian stretch lite on a Raspberry Pi 3B.

Answer (score 17):

Have you created a file in the /Boot directory called "ssh" with no extension?

or setting from

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then -> interfacing options -> enable ssh

EDIT
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Rabbit (+1) - but two concerns: **(1)** I have alreadymanually provisioned certain parts of my Raspbian distribution (installed Java, deployed certain apps/files to particular locations on the file system, used `systemd` to create/manage certain services for me, etc.)...will running `sudo rasp-config` undo any of the settings I've already configured manually? In other words: does it "wipe the slate clean" so to speak? And **(2)** according to [this link](https://elinux.org/RPi_raspi-config) there is no "*Interfacing Options*" menu off of the `raspi-config` main menu, any thoughts?

Comment: No it doesnt touch any settings you dont, think of it like a bios screen

Comment: Ahhh you're talking about a PiZero, I have a 1 Model A, I don't think my version works the same as yours.

Comment: Oh im sorry I thought they all ran the same config app, any creating the file manually should solve it

Comment: They do all run the same config app.  It's part of the OS, which is the same for all models.

Answer (score 2):

Issue the two command as **superuser**

```
systemctl enable ssh.service
systemctl start ssh.service
```