# Control Terminal from smartphone

Tags: keyboard, raspbian-lite

I am using a raspberry pi 2 with raspbian lite, and I wanted to have keyboard control from my phone. So if I hook up my pi to the TV, I can type commands on my phone without needing to connect a keyboard. I found this app called [UnifiedRemote](https://www.unifiedremote.com/) that advertises to do just that.

I downloaded and installed the rpi-deb server onto the pi and installed it. I was able to connect to the server via the app, I can browse files, and send the reboot command. However, I don't have keyboard control and I have followed all the tutorials on their website.

How can I get keyboard control for this app? Are there better options for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ssh client on the smartphone to connect via ssh to the Pi (assuming ssh is running on the Pi, see e.g. [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/73119/19949)), if that is what you want to do.

An (open source) example would be `ConnectBot` for Android phones.

Answer (score 1):

I use [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl) on a daily basis, once I click on the screen (showing the terminal) my keyboard shows.

It's the keyboard of the phone, the one i use for writing sms, etc.
Your app should behave the same way anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need an Android app, I tend to check out IzzyOnDroid lists. [Here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients)'s one for SSH clients / servers. Those little icons with exclamation marks show that a particular app connects to ad providers or trackers, so unless you enjoy being spammed and tracked, pick an app which doesn't have those.

If you want your phone to emulate an actual keyboard, (as in seeing what you type on the TV), you could try an app simulating a [BT keyboard /mouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek&hl=en).