# Is it possible to use a tablet as a Raspberry Pi 4 screen?

Tags: pi-4

I'm thinking about using a Raspberry Pi 4 as a desktop computer replacement, primarily for writing in Emacs. 80 % of the time I will work on it from home.

However, I was wondering how I could use Raspberry Pi 4 without a normal monitor.

So far I found several solutions:

1. [RasPad](https://hackernoon.com/raspad-review-turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-tablet-49957903321) (Raspberry Pi 3)
2. Portable monitor
3. Contraptions where you have the Raspberry Pi attached to the back of a monitor like [this one](https://www.amazon.de/Raspberry-Pi-Touchscreen-Display-Geh%C3%A4use/dp/B01M0AT5O5/ref=sr_1_19?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=raspad&qid=1575749143&sr=8-19).

Is it possible to use an iOS or Android tablet as a monitor for Raspberry Pi 4 so that the the keyboard and the mouse are connected to the Raspberry Pi, and the video output is directed to the tablet (either via physical cable or using something like remote desktop/VNC or, at least, via ssh)?

Comment: It will be possible via [SSH](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90701/control-terminal-from-smartphone), but if you need GUI you will be better off with some sort of HDMI display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many years ago, I used an ssh client on my tablet to connect to the Pis on my network. The ssh server runs on the Pi, and it can be started from the standard configuration utility (raspi-config).

There are also desktop sharing programs. I have no experience with these. Ssh has always been good to me.

Answer (score 4):

All depends on what you mean with

> using as a screen

and what you mean with

> tablet

Using as a primary display, No as your tablet is not having an HDMI or VGA imput. it just has output connectors.

However you can install a VNC server on your raspberry pi and connect from your tablet with a VNC client

You can on the other hand use a Wacom tablet with a display) as a display though I don't know whether the stylus will be accepted as input device (mouse). However I think it should.